# How to set absolute path to MSBuild.exe in Cake scripts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, rider, cakebuild

I want to build my packages (in .NET Framework project) with Rider, using cake script. I want to use the MSBuild Tools under Rider directories instead of the Visual Studio MSBuild Tools directories. Although I couldn't find a way to provide cake an absolute path of the directories. Any ideas?

```cs
Task(CleanSolutionTargetName)
  .Does (() =>
    MSBuild(
        solutionFile,
        settings => settings
                    .SetConfiguration(BuildConfiguration)
                    .SetVerbosity (Verbosity.Quiet)
                    .WithProperty("Platform", SolutionPlatform)
                    .WithTarget("Clean")
                    .UseToolVersion(MSBuildToolVersion.VS2022));

        });
```

I tried to provide an absolute Tools path to the cake script, but nothing worked.

Comment: do not post links on images, use plain text instead

Comment: I don't understand the question, please elaborate your question

Comment: I want cake to use "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2023.2.2\tools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" not the one under the Visual Studio. When I use the function .UseToolsVersion it automatically searches for possible MSBuild.exe paths under Visual Studio but instead I want it to search it for Rider paths or at least to be able to give absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding the path used by [MSBuild](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildAliases/C240F0FB) alias can be done using the [MSBuildSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildSettings/) class either by using the [WithToolPath](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettingsExtensions/DF717F3A) extension method

```cs
MSBuild(
    "./path/to/solution.sln",
    settings => settings
        .WithToolPath("path/to/msbuild.exe")
);
```

or using the [MSBuildSettings](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildSettings/) [ToolPath](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/F6956DA8) property.

```cs
MSBuild(
    "./path/to/solution.sln",
    new MSBuildSettings
    {
        ToolPath = "path/to/msbuild.exe",
    }
);
```

You can read more about overriding MSBuild toolpath in the blog post [VSWhere and Visual Studio 2017 Support](https://cakebuild.net/blog/2017/03/vswhere-and-visual-studio-2017-support) on Cake's website.

Comment: Yes this was the working solution for me yesterday so I implemented it this way, thanks.

Comment: Do you know how Cake "finds" msbuild.exe by default? I have a situation of it using the wrong version and not being able to build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for nuget.exe:

```
        public const string NugetBinaryName = "nuget.exe";
        var nugetExePath = ..path..;
        cakeContext.Tools.RegisterFile(nugetExePath);
```

after this, the whole cake run uses the provided path when it's working with `nuget.exe` in internal steps. To get the saved data, you can use:

```
        cakeContext.Tools.Resolve(NugetBinaryName);
```

Comment: Yes, this is in general good advice, the MSBuild tool resolver has a bit more smarts to it so if using this approach you would need to pass `cakeContext.Tools.Resolve(MSBuildBinaryName);` to MBSuild settings ToolPath property or using the WithToolPath extension method.